# JQuery UI Dialog - Loading form from another page in a dialog and (upon submit) opening processing page in same dialog

Tags: php, jquery

I have pretty hefty form (changeuserjudge.php) that I've loaded from a separate page into a dialog and right now when the form is submitted, the submit page opens in the browser window (not in the open dialog). I'm trying to figure out how I can load the processing form (changeuserjudgeprocess.php) into the same dialog box once the submit button is pressed (and submit the POST variables). I'm trying to refrain from doing the processing on the same page.

dialog script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click').click(function(){
            $("#test").load('changeuserjudge.php?user=tim').dialog({modal:true}); 
            $( "#test" ).dialog( "option", "minWidth", 330 );
            $( "#test" ).dialog( "option", "position", 'top' );             
        });
    });
</script>
```

(test is simply a div on a blank page)

Submit form:

```
<body>
    <div id="judgesMenu">
    <form action="changeuserjudgeprocess.php" method="POST">

    <?php

        $selectedJudges = array();
        if(isset($_GET['user'])){
            echo '<center><b>User: '.ucfirst($_GET['user']).'</b></center><br />';
        }
        echo '<center><input type="checkbox" id="checkall">Select All &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="checknone">Select None</center><br />';
        $listUserJudges = getUserJudges(userNametoID($_GET['user']));
        $arr = array();
        $num = count($listUserJudges);
        if ($num>1){
            foreach ($listUserJudges as $x){
                array_push($arr, judgeIDtoName($x));
            }
        }
        else {
            array_push($arr, $listUserJudges);
        }

        echo '<ul>';
        $list = getActiveJudges();
        foreach ($list as $x){
            $found = 0;
                if (count($arr)>1){
                    foreach ($arr as $y){
                        if ($x == $y){
                            $found = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else { 
                    if (judgeNametoID($x) == $arr[0]){
                        $found = 1;
                    }                       
                }
                if ($found==1){
                    echo '<li>';
                    array_push($selectedJudges, judgeNametoID($x));
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
                    echo '</li>';   
                }
                else {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
                    echo '</li>'; 
                }
        }
            echo '</ul>';
            $_SESSION['selectedJudges']=$selectedJudges;
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo userNametoID($_GET['user']); ?>" />

<br/>
    <p><center><input type="Submit" value="Save Changes" id="sub"/></center></p></div>
    </form></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the jquery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/? This is a really easy way to hijack the form post and submit it via ajax rather than posting it straight to the form url, which as you've found (if I'm understanding correctly) loses your dialog box. Here's a minimal bit of code. How you react to an invalid form submission is the next thing to consider. Let me know if I'm on the right lines and I'll elaborate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#judgeForm").ajaxForm({
        success: function(){
           // add some code in here to react to the success of your form post
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="judgesMenu">
    <form action="changeuserjudgeprocess.php" method="POST" id="judgeForm">

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This plugin will come very much in handy. The form is now being submitted properly, so that's good, however I can't keep the dialog box from exiting and then loading changeuserjudgeprocess.php in the browser window. I tried using return false; without any success. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't got a redirect in the form processing script, have you? Can you post the code where you're setting up the plugin?